# Bouncycastle Java - Generate a tst file from TimestampToken

Tags: java, bouncycastle, trusted-timestamp

I am new on Bouncycastle. I can get `timeStampToken` from TSA server with http connection.

```
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(in).readObject());
TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
response.validate(timeStampRequest);


InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(in).readObject());

TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
response.validate(timeStampRequest);
```

Next, I must generate a file from the `TimeStampResponse` object. The generated files with other client applications has CRL / OCSP url informations but my file does not have this informations. How can i generate this file?

```
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(
            "C:/FORM-003.pdf.tst");
    fos.write(response.getEncoded());
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My timestamp request must have "certReq" attribute to get response which I want.

```
TimeStampRequestGenerator timeStampRequestGenerator = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
timeStampRequestGenerator.setCertReq(true);
```